# php date strange behaviour

Tags: php, date

I have this code

```
$daytime=date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
```

anyone can explain me why in some server the value T returns something like this

```
Tue Oct 10 12:30:50 -03 2017
```

while in another server the value T returns something like this

```
Tue Oct 10 12:30:50 CDT 2017
```

How can I do to always display the CDT value instead of the numeric value -03 ?

Thank you

Comment: I think it has to do with the server configuration

Comment: You'd have to mention the differences between the servers. OS versions? PHP versions? php.ini settings?

Comment: Never heard of that happening... Have you tried using strftime("%Z") instead?

Comment: The servers (cPanel enviroment) have same php version ,version PHP 5.6.30 and same OS , Centos 6

Comment: See my answer below, it depends on which timezone identifier is used when setting the timezone, either in configuration or at runtime. Some timezone identifiers do not have an abbreviation, and will display as -xx or +xx, while other timezones do get abbreviated.

Comment: indeed it's server related , I executed this from console
# date  and I received this , Tue Oct 10 12:47:24 -03 2017 , how to avoid this ? The timezone is America/Sao_Paulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the result of [date_default_timezone_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) on both servers and see the difference. It depends which timezone identifier your server is set to. Some timezone identifiers will display as *+xx* or *-xx* when using the *T* modifier, while identifiers will be abbreviated.

If you want to force a specific timezone in your application without changing server configuration, you can set it using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: In this case (in my code) I can't force date_default_timezone_set(). I would only force to use the not numeric timezone identifiers. Is it possible ?

Comment: It's going to be weird if you're going to abbreviate timezones that don't really have an abbreviation. You could technically generate a mapping, where every timezone would map to a timezone that can be abbreviated, but it's going to give somewhat weird results. For example, it would be weird for someone in Africa to get CET (central european timezone) for their local time, even though the time is the same.

Answer (score 1):

tzdata has stopped using "invented abbreviations", I found this info here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397377/strange-time-zone-abbreviation/397476#397476

This is the cause of the numeric time zone abbreviation.